# WSO2 SOA suite first test

Tags: testing, wso2, suite

Stackoverflow community.
I found out that WSO2 community can be contacted on this site, so I'm going to ask a simple orientation question.

**I would like to deploy a simple "Hello world" service and test it on WSO2 SOA Suite.
How should I proceed** (step by step)**?**

Other doubts related to this aim are:

"Which is WSO2 Carbon function? Is it a suite coordinator on which I can install components (like ESB, Governance Registry, BAM etc.)?"

"Do I need Carbon, ESB and/or Carbon Studio?"

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Carbon is the server foundation based on OSGi. It handles common capabilities like user management, transports, security, logging, clustering, caching and throttling.  All WSO2 products are sets of components running on top of this core framework. 
So the standalone products available for download are made up like this..

- WSO2 Carbon + Service Hosting Related components = WSO2 Application
  Server
- WSO2 Carbon + Mediation/Proxy related components = WSO2 ESB
- WSO2 Carbon + SOA Governance Related components = WSO2 Governence
  Registry
- WSO2 Carbon + BPEL compoents = WSO2 Business Process Server

[This](http://wso2.com/products/platforms)  illustration will help you to understand the capabilities of the whole platform.
To make things more interesting, since this modular archtecture is based on OSGi you can mix and match componets to suit your requirements. For example, if you want to add BPEL support to the WSO2 ESB, simply install the BPEL component into your existing WSO2 ESB.

WSO2 Carbon Studio (recently renamed to Developer Studio) is the Eclipse-Based IDE that helps you with the creation of artifacts with graphical editors, test and debug them within the IDE, and helps deploy them as Carbon Archives (.car) on to your WSO2 Carbon-based servers or onto a WSO2 Stratos-based cloud.

[This](http://rangasiriwardena.blogspot.com/2011/02/creating-simple-axis-serviceaar-file.html) blog describes how to deploy a Hello World service in WSO2 application server.
[This](http://wso2.org/project/carbon-studio/1.0.14/docs/shopping-cart-sample.html) is an advanced sample that uses carbon studio for development and deployment.

Comment: Your answer was much useful. My last (pratical) question on this topic is: if I install the Carbon component (http://wso2.com/products/carbon), has it an independent use, or it must be used together with something?
In this answer I read WSO2Carbon + something, so I suppose that when I download for example the ESB (http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-service-bus), Carbon is implicitly included.
Am I right?
Thanks again!

Comment: You are correct. The bare-bones carbon server is not much useful. You can install components like service hosting, mediation, BPEL to make it useful. ESB or any other product you download, has WSO2 Carbon as the core implicitly included..